# Dockable window -- not maximise

Tags: qt, qdockwidget

I have made a gui which contains dockable windows.

If i click on maximize square on the docable window it comes out but does not occupies the full screen of my gui.

```
Example if i click syntax window it does not occupy full screen
```

Which property do i have to change to make docable window to occupy full screen ?

Please see the attached image.[image]

Comment: There isn't a maximise button on a `QDockWidget`, I think you are referring to the 'Float' button.

Comment: i am referring to square button ...

Comment: Is it not possible to maximize the doc window ?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create your own TitleBarWidget and set it with:

[void QDockWidget::setTitleBarWidget ( QWidget * widget )](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html#setTitleBarWidget)

So you will be able to have as many buttons as you want and maximize it. Following code will help you with it:

```
QDockWidget *dockWidget = qobject_cast<QDockWidget*>(parentWidget());
dockWidget->showMaximized();
```

Edit: To keep the 2 existing buttons functionality:

The docking will be done with [setFloating(bool )](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html#floating-prop). So:

```
QDockWidget *dockWidget = qobject_cast<QDockWidget*>(parentWidget());
dockWidget->setFloating( !dockWidget->isFloating () );
```

For the close, parent [close()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#close) method will work.

And, last edit, i promise ;).

You will need to have the title to show it on your titleWidget:

And it is in [windowTitle : QString property](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html#windowTitle-prop) of parent: